workflow to analyse FAERS longitudinal data
The FDA adverse event reporting system (FAERS) data is a database that contains information on adverse event and medication error reports submitted to FDA. It is published quarterly from 2004 to 2024. Each report consists of several data sets, such as DEMO24Q1, DRUG24Q1, REAC24Q1 (Q1 of 2024) or DEMO12Q2, DRUG12Q2, REAC12Q2(Q2 of 2012) and they can be linked by the variable primaryid. I want to identify all the adverse events associated with one drug from 2004 to 2024.
My proposed workflow to download, import and prepare the data:

Download and unzip all the files from the FAERS website
Import each separate file into R
Join DEMO, DRUG, REAC files by primaryid
Combine the joined data from each quarter into one big file using rbind

Is it a good workflow? Should I rbind the data before performing join?

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.
